# Linux bridge not forwarding traffic after changing bridge ports

Tags: debian, linux-networking, bridge, proxmox

Problem: after changing `bridge-ports` value of a network interface, all networking on that IP stops working. Base system is Proxmox VE 7.4, based on Debian Bullseye.

Background: I have a Proxmox VE home lab with 3 nodes. I've recently decided to move 10gbps networking.

Each node is configured as follows:

- two 1gbps ports (onbaord, Broadcom BCM5716) - `eno1` and `eno2`
- two 10gps ports (PCIE, Broadcom BCM57810) - `enp3s0f0` and `enp30f1`
- five network bridges
- kernel is PVE 5.15.108-1

Each bridge has one bridge-port, which is a sub-interface of one of physical ports on the node. Originally this was configured as:

```
┌─────────────────┐             ┌────────────┐             ┌───────────────────┐
│ cisco switch    │   Trunks    │ eno1       │             │ vmbr10 Admin      │
│                 ├────┬───────►│            ├────┬───────►│ eno1.10           │
│                 │    │        │            │    │        │ IP.10.0.0.4x/24   │
│                 │    │        │            │    │        │ GW.10.0.0.1       │
└─────────────────┘    │        └────────────┘    │        └───────────────────┘
                       │                          │
                       │                          │        ┌───────────────────┐
                       │                          │        │ vmbr20 Secured    │
                       │                          ├───────►│ eno1.20           │
                       │                          │        │                   │
                       │                          │        │                   │
                       │                          │        └───────────────────┘
                       │                          │
                       │                          │        ┌───────────────────┐
                       │                          │        │ vmbr21 Insecure   │
                       │                          ├───────►│ eno1.21           │
                       │                          │        │                   │
                       │                          │        │                   │
                       │                          │        └───────────────────┘
                       │                          │
                       │                          │        ┌───────────────────┐
                       │                          │        │ vmbr100 ISP       │
                       │                          └───────►│ eno1.100          │
                       │                                   │                   │
                       │                                   │                   │
                       │                                   └───────────────────┘
                       │
                       │        ┌────────────┐             ┌───────────────────┐
                       │        │ eno2       │             │ vmbr101 Ceph      │
                       └───────►│            ├────────────►│ eno2.101          │
                                │            │             │ IP.10.0.101.4x/24 │
                                │            │             │                   │
                                └────────────┘             └───────────────────┘
```

Since then I was able to change all except `vmbr10` to use the new 10gps cards:

```
      ┌─────────────────┐             ┌────────────┐             ┌───────────────────┐
      │ cisco switch    │   Trunks    │ eno1       │             │ vmbr10 Admin      │
┌────►│                 ├────┬───────►│            ├────────────►│ eno1.10           │
│     │                 │    │        │            │             │ IP.10.0.0.4x/24   │
│     │                 │    │        │            │             │ GW.10.0.0.1       │
│     └─────────────────┘    │        └────────────┘             └───────────────────┘
│                            │
│                            │        ┌────────────┐
│                            │        │ eno2       │
│                            └───────►│            │
│                                     │            │
│                                     │            │
│                                     └────────────┘
│
│     ┌─────────────────┐             ┌────────────┐             ┌───────────────────┐
│     │ mikrotik switch │   Trunks    │ enp3s0f0   │             │ vmbr20 Secured    │
└────►│                 ├────┬───────►│            ├─────┬──────►│ enp3s0f0.20       │
      │                 │    │        │            │     │       │                   │
      │                 │    │        │            │     │       │                   │
      └─────────────────┘    │        └────────────┘     │       └───────────────────┘
                             │                           │
                             │                           │       ┌───────────────────┐
                             │                           │       │ vmbr21 Insecure   │
                             │                           ├──────►│ enp3s0f0.21       │
                             │                           │       │                   │
                             │                           │       │                   │
                             │                           │       └───────────────────┘
                             │                           │
                             │                           │       ┌───────────────────┐
                             │                           │       │ vmbr100 ISP       │
                             │                           └──────►│ enp3s0f0.100      │
                             │                                   │                   │
                             │                                   │                   │
                             │                                   └───────────────────┘
                             │
                             │        ┌────────────┐             ┌───────────────────┐
                             │        │ enp3s0f1   │             │ vmbr101 Ceph      │
                             └───────►│            ├────────────►│ enps30f1.101      │
                                      │            │             │ IP.10.0.101.4x/24 │
                                      │            │             │                   │
                                      └────────────┘             └───────────────────┘
```

Switching `vmbr10` to use `enp3s0f0` immediately brings connection down and the system will not communicate on that VLAN until I manually re-add `eno1.10` to `bridge-ports` field. It can be configured as `bridge-ports eno1.10 enp3s0f0.10` but will only use `eno1.10`.

STP is not enabled, and these bridges are not learning any MAC addresses.

This is not limited to Proxmox services but affects everything, including SSH and ping - this leads me to think this is a behaviour/configuration issue.

What I have examined and tried:

- changing `bridge-ports` then rebooting
- using `tcpdump` to examine traffic at physical interface and `enp3s0f0` is receiving VLAN10 traffic for the node
- using `tcpdump` to examine traffic on `vmbr10` - only broadcast ARP requests are seen
- using `brctl` to check port state and it is `forwarding`
- checked `iptables` and `ebtables` - I do not use either and all chains/tables are in default accept state and do not have any rules

For reference here is the current content of `/etc/network/interfaces` - this is generated by Proxmox VE's Network config editor.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

iface eno2 inet manual

iface enp3s0f0 inet manual

iface enp3s0f1 inet manual

auto vmbr10
iface vmbr10 inet static
    address 10.0.0.41/24
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    bridge-ports eno1.10
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids 2-4094
#VLAN 10 Admin

auto vmbr100
iface vmbr100 inet manual
    bridge-ports enp3s0f0.100
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids 2-4094
#VLAN 10 ISP

auto vmbr101
iface vmbr101 inet static
    address 10.0.101.41/24
    bridge-ports enp3s0f1.101
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids 2-4094
#VLAN 101 Ceph Backend

auto vmbr20
iface vmbr20 inet manual
    bridge-ports enp3s0f0.20
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids 2-4094
#VLAN 20 Trusted

auto vmbr21
iface vmbr21 inet manual
    bridge-ports enp3s0f0.21
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids 2-4094
#VLAN 21 Untrusted
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to further debug this?